# How do I output an individual character when using char *[] = "something"

Tags: c++, pointers, char

I've been playing with pointers to better understand them and I came across something I think I should be able to do, but can't sort out how.  The code below works fine - I can output "a", "dog", "socks", and "pants" - but what if I wanted to just output the 'o' from "socks"?  How would I do that?

```
char *mars[4] = { "a", "dog", "sock", "pants" };

for ( int counter = 0; counter < 4; counter++ )
{
  cout << mars[ counter ];
}
```

Please forgive me if the question is answered somewhere - there are 30+ pages of C++ pointer related question, and I spent about 90 minutes looking through them, as well as reading various (very informative) articles, before deciding to ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mars[i][j]` will print the `j`'th character of the `i`'th string.

So `mars[2][1]` is 'o'.

Comment: Ugh...that was ridiculously simple.  I was thinking it would have just produced a one dimensional array.

Answer (score 2):

As has been pointed out before, strings are arrays. In fact, this concept is carried on the the [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)-class (which, by the way, is the preferred way of representing strings in C++), which implements all the requirements of an [STL-Sequence](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/basic_string.html). Furthermore it implements the array-subscript operator. That means the expression:

```
mars[i][j]
```

would also work if `mars` was declared as

```
std::vector< std::string > mars;
```

which is much more the C++ way of handling this. I realize you are doing this to learn about pointers, but I just thought I'd add this for your information. Also, when learning about pointers in C++, you should also learn about [iterators](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Iterators.html), as they are [generalizations of pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728190/how-are-iterators-and-pointers-related).

Answer (score 1):

```
cout << mars[2][1] ;
```

`mars` is an array of `char *` so to get the individual char you have to index into the array of char

Answer (score 0):

`mars[counter]` is of type `char *`, pointing to a zero-terminated string of characters. So you could:

```
for ( int counter = 0; counter < 4; counter++ ) 
{ 
  char * str = mars[ counter ]; 
  size_t len = strlen(str);

  if (len >= 2)
    cout << str[1]; 
}
```

Comment: This answer is above my head, unfortunately :9

Answer (score 0):

Since others have suggested easy way, please also find one round-about way of doing it ;)

```
char *myChar = &mars[ 1 ][0];
int nPosOfCharToLocate = 1;
myChar = myChar + nPosOfCharToLocate;
cout <<*myChar<<endl;
```

Comment: Wimpy. I'd use `char const *myChar = (mars.begin()+1)->data();`.