# displaying minimum and maximum of a vector C++

Tags: c++, vector, max, min

I have written code that outputs the total rainfall for a set amount of years. My question is how would I just display the year with the largest and smallest rainfall i.e the maximum and minimum of the dataset with the corresponding year.

The output i have so far is: (but i just want the maximum and minimum of the vector with the corresponding year so with this output, only 2011 and 2012 should be displayed)

Comment: What do you think you should do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874802/how-can-i-get-the-max-or-min-value-in-a-vector-c

Comment: I've already looked at that but it doesn't help me display the year also @ub3rst4r

Comment: @MatsPetersson I'm not sure on how to display the year aswell, thats why i've posted the question on here

Comment: @noodle: please edit your code with the correct indent, it will help people to understand your code easier...For your question, you can create a vector to hold all the value of your rainfall for each year. Then, do a for loop to find your min and max value.

Comment: @HoangMinh I'm extremely new to c++ and I’m not really sure what the correct indentation sorry,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

std::max_element
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max_element/
std::min_element
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min_element/

Comment: would this also display the corresponding year as that is what is causing the difficulty?

Comment: After using std::max_element and std::min_element use std::distance (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/distance/) to get the index of the max and min elements. The year corresponding to the max element is as follows: yearly[iMaxElement]. The year corresponding to the min element is yearly[iMinElement].

Comment: The max and min now work perfectly thank you but could you go into more detail about how to display the year aswell?

Comment: I already answered that question in my previous comment about std::distance. Here is some untested code. I do not have time to test it for you.

auto itMaxElement = std::max_element(rainfall.begin(), rainfall.end());
auto iMaxElement = std::distance(rainfall.begin(), itMaxElement);
// iMaxElement is now the index of the max element.
auto yearThatCorrespondsToMaxElement = yearly[iMaxElement];