# Why does std::min only support initializer_list?

Tags: c++, std

We can use `std::min` in below way:

```
// 1.
int a = 1, b = 2;
std::min(a, b);

// 2.
std::min({1,2,3,4});
```

But why can't use a `std::vector` or `std::list`, Because the param in the template is `initializer_list`.

```
template <class T, class Compare>
  pair<T,T> minmax (initializer_list<T> il, Compare comp);
```

What is the reason for this design?

Comment: You may use `std::max_element` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874802/how-can-i-get-the-max-or-min-value-in-a-vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To explain "why it doesn't accept a container", take the semantic into consideration:

`std::min({ "foo", "bar", "hello" })`

The semantic of `std::min()` means "find the minimum value in the input parameters". Thus `std::min()`/`std::max()` takes two arguments, or an initializer_list as "more arguments".

`std::min()` doesn't provide the ability to "iterate through a container", because a container is considered as "a parameter".

To find the min value in a container, there is `std::min_element()`, and eerorika's suggestion `std::ranges::min()` in C++20 should be better.

For `std::min_element()` usage, you may refer to [How can I get the max (or min) value in a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874802/).

Comment: ye, I found std::min_element is used for vector.

Answer (score 3):

> *"The more they overthink the plumbing, the easier it is to stop up the drain."* – Commander Montgomery Scott

The purpose of `std::min` is to return the smaller of its parameters. Simple and succinct. As with your own designs, it is better for a function (or function template) to do one thing well than to do many things poorly. Thus, `std::min` has no knowledge of containers. It simply knows how to take two things and compare them. Knowledge of containers was instead granted to `std::min_element`. Between the two templates, most use cases were covered.

One case that was not covered was finding the minimum of more than two elements when those elements were not the elements of a (range within a) container. This case could be handled by daisy-chaining `std::min`, but it is somewhat awkward to do so. For C++11, it was decided that the benefits of handling more parameters outweighed the cost of complicating the template, as long as the complications were kept to a minimum. Thus a single, simple mechanism for supplying an arbitrary number of arguments was chosen, namely `std::initializer_list`. There is no need to allow arbitrary containers because `std::min_element` already covers that situation.

Comment: I studied it just to figure out the basic library.

Answer (score 2):

> But why can't use a std::vector or std::list, Because the param in the template is initializer_list.

Because there is no overload that would accept a vector or a list. Those are not initialiser lists.

Since C++20 you can use `std::ranges::min` into which you can pass either of those containers or indeed any range. Prior to that, there is `std::min_element` which works with any pair of iterators.