# Wrong use of std::copy?

Tags: c++, std

Here is a simple test program that illustrates the problem I faced:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
typedef unsigned char Byte;

int main( )
{
    uint32_t ui32 = 12;
    size_t sizeofUi32 = sizeof ui32;
    cout << "sizeofUi32: " << sizeofUi32 << endl;
    vector<Byte> v(10);
    std::copy(&ui32, &ui32 + sizeof ui32, &v[4]);

    uint32_t result = 0;
    std::copy(&v[4], &v[4] + sizeof ui32, &result);

    cout << "Result: " << result << " sizeofUi32: " << sizeofUi32 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
sizeofUi32: 4    
Result: 12 sizeofUi32: 17179869184
```

I thought this issue might be due to std::copy accepting iterators not pointers, but from what I got in SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728190/how-are-iterators-and-pointers-related),

> a pointer IS an iterator

So there must be a simple issue with my sample code, that I' missing. But I can't spot it.
Could you please explain, what's wrong here?

**EDIT 1:**

So from the answers I got the idea, that to deserialize a vector of bytes, if I know the right order and types of stored data in vector, I can avoid using std::copy and just assign vector values to variables of proper types. It works, but is it safe?

```
uint32_t a = v[4];
uint8_t b = v[8];
```

Comment: You may want to use `std::copy_n`

Comment: @AlexandreC., right! Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The immediate problem is here:

> ```
> std::copy(&ui32, &ui32 + sizeof ui32, &v[4]);
>                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

`&ui32` has type `uint32_t *`, and adding anything to that already takes into account the object's size. You're effectively attempting to copy `sizeof ui32` `uint32_t` objects, but you only have a single one, so you should be using `+ 1`.

That aside, using `std::copy` with pointers of different types is likely not to give you the results you expect. It has the effect of `v[4] = ui32;`, which works as long as `ui32` is inside `Byte`'s range, which it is here, but that's not something you can rely on in general.

The second `std::copy` has roughly the same problem, but in the opposite direction.

What you could do is:

```
std::copy((Byte*) &ui32, (Byte*) (&ui32 + 1), &v[4]);
// or std::copy((Byte*) &ui32, (Byte*) &ui32 + sizeof ui32, &v[4]);
...
std::copy(&v[4], &v[4] + sizeof ui32, (Byte*) &result);
```

Comment: So, from what I've got from your answer, I need to cast pointers used in `std::copy` to the same type to achieve the desired result, right?

Comment: @rightaway717 Not just to the same type, specifically to `Byte*` (`unsigned char*`). If you attempt to convert the other way around, if you attempt to use `uint32_t*` for all three arguments, you might find that `&v[4]` is not suitably aligned.

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn’t with `std::copy` but with pointer arithmetic. As you’ve said, “a pointer IS an iterator”. But more importantly, it’s *strongly typed*. So a pointer-to-`uint32_t` is different from a pointer-to-`unsigned char`.

Adding `&ui32 + sizeof ui32` effectively treats `ui32` as if it were the beginning of a contiguous array with 4 elements (of type `uint32_t`).