# Why std::istream_iterator constructor returning pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator

As seen example below `iit` object initialization returns as pointer, can anyone explain how is returns as pointer from constructor?

```
int main() 
{

 std::istream_iterator<int> iit (std::cin);
 std::cout  << *iit;
 return 0;

}
```

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how *iterators in general* work. I recommend that you [get a couple of good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) to read.

Comment: `iit` is an iterator (something what supposed to behave like a pointer). Please read your handbook about iterators.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterator = pointer? Or what is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950285/iterator-pointer-or-what-is-it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no pointers here. Seeing `*iit` in the code doesn't mean that `iit` is a pointer - C++ allows [*operator overloading*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) on arbitrary operators.

`std::istream_iterator<int>` simply [overloads unary `operator*`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator/operator*).

Answer (score 3):

**`iit` is not a pointer, and your `*iit` is a reference to a `int`.** See, this is the declaration of [`std::istream_iterator::operator*`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator/operator*):

```
const T& operator*() const;
```

***Template class* `std::istream_iterator` overloads the unary `*` *operator***, in which it *"Returns a [...] reference to the current element"*.

You can [read here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) about the different kinds of *iterators*, and get to understand the entire concept of it and fundamental part it has in C++.

Comment: @Kad Prior to last edit this was misquotation and thus misleading. Now fixed. Apologies.