# How to parse this vector through its 0th postition reference

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, iterator

I am trying to parse this simple array from the reference of its first element.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>     

int main()
{
    vector<int> vec3 { 1,2,3,4,5};
    for( vector<int>::iterator ptr = &vec3[0]; ptr != vec3.end(); ++ptr )
    {
        cout << *ptr << " ";
    }
}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
[Error] conversion from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<int> >::value_type* {aka int*}' to non-scalar type 'std::vector<int>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >}' requested
```

What's the problem?

Comment: You should do `vector<int>::iterator ptr= vec3.begin()` or, better yet `auto ptr= vec3.begin()`

Comment: And even better: `for (auto& el: vec3) { cout << el << ' '; }`

Comment: Thanks for replying @Mirko . I know these methods but i was wondering why can't we give it first element reference and iterate over the array.

Comment: Possible dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950285/iterator-pointer-or-what-is-it/30950304#30950304

Comment: You can, but not mixing things. `&vec3[a]` is not an iterator. It's an `int*`. You can't compare it to `end()` either; you should do: `for (int* ptr= &vec3[0]; ptr != &vec3[vec3.size()]; ptr++)` or something along those lines

Comment: Thanks for clarification @Mirko

Comment: @Mirko Technically, it _is_ a kind of iterator ... it's just not the same kind of iterator as `vector<int>::iterator` ;)

Answer (score 7):

Iterators of the class std::vector are not necessary pointers (though they can be defined such a way and indeed some old implementations of the class `std::vector` defined its iterators as pointers.). They usually are defined as classes.

And the compiler error says that there is no implicit conversion from the type `value_type *` to the type of the iterator.

So in general you have to write

```
vector<int> vec3 { 1,2,3,4,5};
for( vector<int>::iterator ptr = vec3.begin(); ptr != vec3.end(); ++ptr )
{
    cout << *ptr << " ";
}
```

However in this particular case you could use the range-based for statement.

```
vector<int> vec3 { 1,2,3,4,5};
for ( const auto &item : vec3 )
{
    cout << item << " ";
}
```

If you indeed want to deal with pointers then the loop can look for example the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> vec3 { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    for( auto ptr = vec3.data(); ptr != vec3.data() + vec3.size(); ++ptr )
    {
        std::cout << *ptr << ' ';
    }       

    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let `vec` be an object of type `std::vector<int>`, then `vec.end()` returns an `std::vector<int>::iterator` which can be different from the corresponding raw pointer, `int *`. One of the reasons for this would be to allow support for debugging and error checking (e.g., out-of-boundaries access).

As a consequence, you must write `&(*vec.begin())` to obtain the address of the first element of the vector instead of just `vec.begin()` since the latter doesn't necessarily return a raw pointer.

You can easily check whether or not `&vec[0]` and `vec.end()` have the same type on your implementation:

```
auto a = vec.end(); 
auto b = &vec[0];
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(a), decltype(b)>::value, "not same type");
```

In my case:

> `error: static_assert failed "not same type"
>      static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(a), decltype(b)>::value...`