# C++ Terminology Reference and Iterator

Tags: c++

Wikipedia tells me that

> Reference is a simple reference datatype that is less powerful but safer than the pointer type inherited from C

I am learning C++ and I came across the function vector::front().

In the documentation it says the fuction

> Returns a reference to the first element in the vector.

However, as shown in the code below, the return value is treated as not the reference but the element itself.

```
vector<int> my_vector(1); // initialising a vector
my_vector.push_back(10); // inserting 10
int number = my_vector.front() + 1; // number = 11
```

If my_vector.front() is a reference to the first element, shouldn't it be dereferenced with (*) in order to access the value?

Seeing that

`*my_vector.begin() == my_vector.front() == 10`

and I can do arithmetics to the iterator, should I think of iterators as something similar to pointers in C, and think of reference as a value?

Comment: Also, this answers your question about iterators vs pointers: [How are iterators and pointers related?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2728190/3425536)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... should I think of iterators as something similar to pointers in C, and think of reference as a value?

Yes, iterators implement pointer like behavior.

Think of references as *alias* for a specific value stored.

Answer (score 2):

`my_vector.front()` returns, as you already stated, a *reference* to the first element, not an iterator/pointer. References do not need to be dereferenced in order for their values to be used.

> and I can do arithmetics to the iterator, should I think of iterators
>   as something similar to pointers in C, and think of reference as a
>   value?

Exactly.
Iterators are basically glorified pointers used for container access while references are more or less `*pointer` (dereferenced pointers).

Answer (score 2):

When an object is passed or returned by reference, using this reference is like using the original object itself (including modifying it !).  Try for example:

```
...
my_vector.front() = number *2; 
cout << number<<" "<<  my_vector.front() <<endl;
```

Iterators are pointer like.  You have to dereference them (with `*` or `->`) to access to the object it refers to.  The arithmetic possibilities [depend however strongly on the kind of iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/) and might be much more limited than for pointers:

```
my_vector.begin()+10    // ok for a random access iterator on vectors, not for 
                        // bidirectional iterators on iterators on a list
```