# Why am I unable to pass an iterator to string as an argument to the function strcat()?

Tags: c++, pointers

I've been constantly getting this error for the following block of program, isn't an **iterator** also a **pointer** when using such string data types?

```
 error: cannot convert 'std::basic_string<char>::iterator 
 {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >}'
 to 'const char*' for argument '2' to 'char* strcat(char*, const char*)'
 strcat(temp, str1.begin());
                        ^





            int areRotations(string str1, string str2)
            {
              int size1   = str1.length();
              int size2   = str2.length();
              char* temp= new char[size1+size2+1];
              void *ptr;
              if (size1 != size2)
              return 0;


              strcat(temp, str1.begin());
              strcat(temp, str1.begin());

              /* Now check if str2 is a substring of temp */
               ptr = strstr(temp, str2);


               if (ptr != NULL)
               return 1;
               else
               return 0;
            }
```

Comment: Why do you use `strcat` with `std::string`? Or, rather, why isn't `temp` a `std::string`?

Comment: Iterators are not pointers. Pointers are iterators.

Comment: `str1.begin()` and `C`? How exactly?

Comment: You know that you can concatenate std::strings using `+`?

Comment: This function boils down to a single line: `return str1.size() == str2.size() && (str1+str1).find(str2) != string::npos;`

Comment: @LiMuBei Yes I know that, thanks for the down-vote anyways!

Comment: Iterators *behave* very much like pointers - but they don't (necessarily) have the same type as pointers.  Your code has a bug given `areRotations( "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw", "1")` - you will overflow temp.  Also you have a memory leak.  You want `bool areRotations(const std::string& str1, const std::string& str2) { return (str1+str1).find(str2) != std::string::npos;}`

Comment: @MartinBonner Hey I've allotted temp variable a **space** of char* temp= new char[size1+size2+1]; Isn't that sufficient?

Comment: Nothing like receiving advice and then refusing to follow it.

Comment: @paddy Hey I've solved it!! by passing the pointer to string as an argument....thanks :)

Comment: All other proposed solutions are better than what you just described.

Comment: @paddy yes I get it exactly, but I was pondering over the properties of strcat() function....thanks again :V

Comment: Then you should probably accept the answer that mentions using `c_str` to obtain a pointer to the buffer, amongst other explanations.  Don't forget to free your temporary memory with the correct array-delete operator on all control paths, or use `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @YashKant:  No.  In my example, you would allows 23+1+1 characters, and then copy 23+23+1 characters in.  That won't fit.  *pause* Ah!  I missed the `if (size1!=size2) return 0;`.  In that case the allocation is confusing but safe (better would be `2*size1+1`).

Comment: @YashKant I did not down-vote. My comment was not ill-intended. I was simply wondering why you chose to use strcat with std::strings...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ask,

> **”** isn't an iterator also a pointer when using such string data types

No, not necessarily.

For `std::string` it *can* be a pointer because `std::string` has a guaranteed contiguous buffer, so incrementing a pointer moves it forward in the buffer. However, I don't know of any extant C++ standard library implementation where it is a pointer.

A simple way to get a pointer to the buffer, that works also for an empty string, is to use the `data` member function. When you know that the string is non-empty you can also use `&s[0]` for this. A simple way to get a pointer to non-modifiable zero-terminated string, is to use the `c_str` member function.

---

Instead of `strcat`, with `std::string` you can just use `+` or `+=`.

Answer (score 3):

Pointer are iterators. the other way around is not always true. You can find here more information:
[How are iterators and pointers related?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728190/how-are-iterators-and-pointers-related)

However you are mixing up quite some things...  C, C++. A simple C++ solution to your problem which simply uses std::string would be:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
bool areRotations(const string& str1, const string& str2)
{
    const string temp = str1 + str1;
    return ((temp.find(str2)!=std::string::npos) && (str1.size()==str2.size()));
}

int main()
{
    const std::string str1 = "hello";
    const std::string str2 = "lohel";
    cout << areRotations(str1,str2) << endl;
}
```

Comment: The original had a test that str1 and str2 were the same length.  You might want  to add that.