# Passing pointer instead of iterator to std::copy

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator, copy, indexoutofboundsexception

Found this code while doing code review:

```
std::array<uint, 10> expArray2 = {92,130,169,951,634,187,377,233,865,944};
copy(&expArray2[0], &expArray2[10], back_inserter(expected));
                        ^~~~Is this Undefined behavior as ArrayIndexOutOfBoundAccess?
```

Is it same as (what I propose) :

```
std::copy ( expArray2, expArray2+10, expected.begin() );
```

My colleague says 1.) both are same 2.) there is no undefined behavior?

I explained to him that pointers and iterator are two [different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2728318/1465553) things, along with [std::copy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/) signature:

```
template <class InputIterator, class OutputIterator>
  OutputIterator copy (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, OutputIterator result);
```

Could someone please confirm/explain this to me *if I am wrong anywhere*?

Comment: Pointers are a kind of iterator. That's even mentioned in the link you provided.

Comment: Yes, but my major concern is arrayIndexOutOfBoundAccess.

Comment: Seems like the core of this question is about the expression `&expArray2[10]`. In that case, this looks relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988158/take-the-address-of-a-one-past-the-end-array-element-via-subscript-legal-by-the

Comment: Yes you understood it right.

Answer (score 3):

This *std::copy* usage with *std::array* is perfectly valid. Basically *std::copy* works with pointers denoting the input range because pointers satisfy all the requirements of the input iterators.

As for taking *begin* end *end* of the input range as *&expArray2[0]* and *&expArray2[10]* it is also fine because *std::array* is guaranteed to manage a continuous underlying array so you can deal with this array as with any usual C-style array.

As for me, I would prefer to use *std::begin* and *std::end* inside *std::copy*:

```
std::copy(std::cbegin(expArray2), std::cend(expArray2),
    std::back_inserter(expected));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your colleague is right.

Iterator is a concept with requirements (that they can be dereferenced and incremented is a minimum) that pointers fullfil.

Also, ranges in C++ are half open, which means that the second (last) iterator passed to algorithms needs to be **one past** the elements you want included in the range. It's never dereferenced (that's guaranteed by C++ standard), so there's no UB the code you posted.

NOTE: `expected.begin()` is not the same as `back_inserter(expected)`. With the former you need a container big enough to hold the resulting range, while the latter automaticaly expands it.

Comment: You might want to comment on the use of `back_inserter(expected)` vs. `expected.begin()`.

Comment: @user2899162 Done that. You're right, something's fishy about it.

Comment: That difference I know, vector is not provided size before. So its ok.