# How do I make for_each work with templates?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, templates, foreach

I am new to c++ and am trying to understand how *for_each* works. So I wanted to see how it works with templates and tried this code but it gives out an error

When I tried to use the for each in the `main` it worked as it should have

```
template <class T>
void forEachTest(T a[])
{
    for (int x : a)
        cout << x << endl;
}
int main()
{
    int a[5] = { 10, 50, 30, 40, 20 };
    forEachTest(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is unrelated to templates. The same thing happens if you replace the template with a regular function.

Answer (score 8):

> I am new to c++ and am trying to understand how *for_each* works

If you meant the *[range-based `for`-loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)* as *for_each* here, it just syntactic sugar for the *[iterator based loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for#Explanation)*, which works for any objects for which *begin* and *end* member functions defined.

```
auto&& __range = range_expression;                     // (until C++17)
for (auto __begin = begin_expr, __end = end_expr; __begin != __end; ++__begin) 
{
    range_declaration = *__begin;
    loop_statement
}
```

The *begin* and *end* iterators for an array(e.g. `int a[size]`) can easily be found by `a` and `a + size` respectively, as *[iterators are generalizations of pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728190/how-are-iterators-and-pointers-related)*. 
Therefore, whenever iterate through an array(in a range-based `for`-loop), the compiler should be knowing the `size` of the underlying array.

In your version, the passed array will be deduced to `int*`(no size information available) instead of the actual type `int a[5]`.

There are few options, by which the passed array can be deduced to the actual type:

- **Option - 1**: Provide a non - type parameter for *size* of the array,
  with the following syntax.

  ```
  template <typename T, std::size_t N>
  void forEachTest(T const (&a)[N])
  //               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  {
   for (int x : a)
       std::cout << x << std::endl;
  }
  ```
- **Option - 2**: pass it by *const - reference*, since the values are not
  being modified inside the function.

  ```
  template <typename T>
  void forEachTest(T const (&a))
  //              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  {
   for (int x : a)
       std::cout << x << std::endl;
  }
  ```
- **Option - 3**: *[forward the array perfectly](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/cplusplus/rvalue_references_and_perfect_forwarding.html)* with forwarding reference.

  ```
  template <typename T>
  void forEachTest(T&& a)
  //               ^^^^^^
  {
   for (int x : a)
       std::cout << x << std::endl;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 3):

When you use

```
template <class T>
void forEachTest(T a[]) 
{
    for (int x : a)
        cout << x << endl;
}
```

the size of the array is not known in the function. Hence, there is no way to iterate over the elements of `a`.

You need to use a slightly different function template.

```
template <class T, size_t N>
void forEachTest(T (&a)[N]) 
{
    for (int x : a)
        cout << x << endl;
}
```