# c++ vector with two parameters

Tags: c++, vector, parameters

I don't quite understand what the following does:

```
 std::vector<const char*> getRequiredExtensions()
{
    uint32_t glfwExtensionCount = 0;
    const char** glfwExtensions;
    glfwExtensions = glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions(&glfwExtensionCount);

    std::vector<const char*> extensions(glfwExtensions, glfwExtensions + glfwExtensionCount);

    if (enableValidationLayers) {
        extensions.push_back(VK_EXT_DEBUG_UTILS_EXTENSION_NAME);
    }

    return extensions;
}
```

I don't understand this line:

```
std::vector<const char*> extensions(glfwExtensions, glfwExtensions + glfwExtensionCount);
```

What exactly does it do? And what does glfwExtensions resolve to, I only get that it's a double pointer (Which is also a new concept for me).
And what does the glfwExtensions + glfwExtensionCount mean?

thanks for any help!

Comment: have you read some documentation on `std::vector`? If yes, where does the confusion arise from?

Comment: First of all, I'm new to c++. So I don't understand how these double pointers work.

Comment: trick with double pointers is: ignore the fact that they're double pointers, that's not a "special thing" at all. It's really just a pointer, and the thing it points at happens to be a pointer. That's all. Replace, mentally `const char*` with `some_type`, and your complicated `const char** glfwExtensions;` becomes `some_type* glfwExtensions;`, and that's much less confusing, right?

Comment: It's using _overload 5_ @ [`std::vector::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) (the one taking two iterators)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's concentrate on the following line of code:

```cpp
std::vector<const char*> extensions(glfwExtensions, glfwExtensions + glfwExtensionCount);
```

This declares `extensions` as a variable of the templated `std::vector<typename T>` type, where the `T` type resolves to `const char*` (that is, it declares a vector whose elements are each pointers to constant character data). This vector object is initialized using the constructor that takes two *iterator* arguments – the form (5) on [this cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

A point of confusion here may be how the arguments are iterators: well, [pointers are also iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2728190/10871073) (in many ways). In this case, the `const char** glfwExtensions;` line declares a variable that points to a `const char*` (which is the type of the vector's elements), and the call to `glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions` makes this point to the beginning of an array of such (`const char*`) pointers and sets the `glfwExtensionCount` variable to the number of elements in that array. Further, adding the size of an array to a pointer to its first elements yields a pointer to "one past the end" of the array – which is equivalent to an STL "end" iterator.

Thus, the two arguments to the constructor are, effectively, acting as `std::begin(glfwExtensions)` and `std::end(glfwExtensions)` – but those functions can't be used directly, because `glfwExtensions` is *not* an array of known size in this context.

Answer (score 1):

It may help if you compare `const char** glfwExtensions;` with the famous variable `argv` in `main`:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char **argv) //  or:  char *argv[]
```

`glfwExtensions` can likewise be seen as an array of `const char*`

So, after

```cpp
glfwExtensions = glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions(&glfwExtensionCount);
```

you can therefore

```cpp
for(uint32_t i = 0; i < glfwExtensionCount; ++i) {
    // access   glfwExtensions[i]    here
    // or     *(glfwExtensions + i)  (same thing)
}
```

Since `glfwExtensions` is a `const char**`, then `glfwExtensions + i` is also a `const char**`, `i` steps from `glfwExtensions + 0`.
The asterisk in `*(glfwExtensions + i)` means that you *dereference* the pointer to get a reference to the value it's pointing *at* - which, since you have a `const char**`, is a `const char*`.

`glfwExtensions` is a pointer to the first element in `glfwExtensionCount` number of elements and you can use `glfwExtensions + i` to get a pointer to any of those elements.

The line you wonder about

```cpp
std::vector<const char*> extensions(glfwExtensions,
                                    glfwExtensions + glfwExtensionCount);
```

is using the `vector` constructor that takes two *iterators* and populates the `vector` with the dereferenced values, the actual `const char*`s.

`glfwExtensions + glfwExtensionCount` is pointing one element past the last element. You are only allowed to deference the elements in the range `[glfwExtensions + 0, glfwExtensions + glfwExtensionCount - 1]` so this pointer is used to tell the `vector` where to stop reading values.

It's similar to doing this:

```cpp
const char** current = glfwExtensions;
const char** one_past_last = glfwExtensions + glfwExtensionCount;        

std::vector<const char*> extensions;
extensions.reserve(std::distance(current, one_past_last));

for(;current != one_past_last; ++current) // stop at one_past_last
    // dereference current to get the value it is pointing at:
    extensions.push_back(*current);
```

Answer (score 0):

So...

```
const char** glfwExtensions;
```

It is a pointer to a pointer (pointer to string)
This mean that when you to this...

```
glfwExtensions + glfwExtensionCount
```

The: const char** glfwExtensions; is like a vector and with + count you access its next element.

To simplify the: glfwExtensions + glfwExtensionCount is like vector::at(glfwExtensionCount)

And basicly in this code:

```
std::vector<const char*> extensions(glfwExtensions, glfwExtensions + glfwExtensionCount);
```

You are creating std::vector from begin which is glfwExtensions to end
which is glfwExtensions + glfwExtensionCount